# android LayoutInflater setText get text from strings + position

Tags: android, string, position, settext

I have a viewPager that get its text from the string.xml.

The plan is, depending on the position of ViewPager, it gets the text from strings, for example if the user is in page 3 it should get text from string name="page3".

the important issue is I want to write my code in layoutInflater not in Activity.

here is the code that works just in Activity:

```
String name = "page" + position;
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", getPackageName());
tv.setText(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you are getting identifier means id of particular string in R.java but not string.

So you can do one thing like this

```
int[] arr = {R.string.page1,R.string.page2,R.string.page3};
tv.setText(getResources.getString(arr[pos]));
```